# SQL Postgres query very slow with multiple tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, sql-update

I am using Postgres.

**Schema**

```
+------------+  +-----------+  +---------------------+
| employee   |  | contact   |  | powwowpersalmapping |
+------------+  +-----------+  +---------------------+
| member_id  |  | member_id |  | id_number           |
| staff_code |  | idnumber  |  | persal_number       |
+------------+  +-----------+  +---------------------+
```

**Data**

[image]

**Goal**

As you can see, the `staff_code` is blank, so I am trying to set the `staff_code` on the `employee` table with the `persal_number` on the `powwowpersalmapping` table.

**Question**

How do I construct the `UPDATE` query to copy the `persal_number` to the `staff_code`?

[image]

**Problem**

I am creating an `UPDATE` query, but the equivalent `SELECT` query is very slow, so I think the `UPDATE` query will be slow too.

**SQL**

I have the following:

If I run this `SELECT` query with table joins. it runs pretty fast.

```
SELECT e.* FROM employee e
INNER JOIN contact c ON c.member_id = e.member_id 
INNER JOIN powwowpersalmapping m ON m.id_number = c.idnumber
WHERE e.staff_code is null or coalesce(e.staff_code, '') = '';
```

Then I run this `SELECT` query with multiple tables (no joins). it runs very slow.

```
SELECT e.* FROM employee e
, contact c, powwowpersalmapping m 
WHERE c.member_id = e.member_id 
AND m.id_number = c.idnumber
AND e.staff_code is null or coalesce(e.staff_code, '') = '';
```

So I am constructing an `UPDATE` query (not run yet), and have the following so far, but I am sure it will also be very slow.

```
UPDATE employee e
SET e.staff_code = m.persal_number
FROM contact c, powwowpersalmapping m 
WHERE c.member_id = e.member_id 
AND m.id_number = c.idnumber
AND e.staff_code is null or coalesce(e.staff_code, '') = '';
```

How about the following?

```
UPDATE employee e
SET e.staff_code = (
    SELECT m.persal_number FROM employee e
    INNER JOIN contact c ON c.member_id = e.member_id 
    INNER JOIN powwowpersalmapping m ON m.id_number = c.idnumber
    WHERE e.staff_code is null or coalesce(e.staff_code, '') = ''
);
```

Comment: The first two queries are not equivalent. They return different columns.

Comment: Your second query implicitly does cross joins and filters. Can you explain what is the point of second query (and likely first one) when your intent is to return fields only from employee?

Comment: @CetinBasoz, thanks for your reply.  I am trying to set the `staff_code` on the `employee` table with the `persal_number` on the `powwowpersalmapping` table.  However, I have to use the `contact` table as a join table.

Comment: @Richard, sorry I am having a hard time to understand. Could you please supply soe sample data with desired output. The queries don't make sense to me as is.

Comment: @CetinBasoz, I have updated my question to include more info (sample data).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use joins in the `UPDATE` statement after the `FROM` clause:

```
UPDATE employee e
SET staff_code = m.persal_number
FROM contact c INNER JOIN powwowpersalmapping m 
ON m.id_number = c.idnumber
WHERE c.member_id = e.member_id AND COALESCE(e.staff_code, '') = '';
```

Since the `SELECT` query runs fast (I believe there are indexes for all the related columns) this will also run fast.
If you could also get rid of the `COALESCE()` function it would be even faster.
Is the column `staff_code` empty? If yes, then remove `AND COALESCE(e.staff_code, '') = ''`.